# Can i have drag and drop between two grids with same store? (ext JS)

Tags: extjs

I want to drag and drop entries from one grid to another. The grids use the same store. I'm using a store that uses a database. Everything works fine except for the fact that if i drag and drop from one grid to another, The entry i move, goes where i put it, appears in both grids, but after a refresh it disappears from database. I'm guessing that it thinks i'm removing the entry from the store, but doesn't realize that i put it back in the same store but in 2nd grid. Other CRUD operations work, except for this case. Autosync is turned on for the store. And from what i can see on the network, when i move an entry it only calls destroyUsers.

Do i have to use separate stores with same data for the grids? Or is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You must have two separate stores for inter-grid D&D otherwise one grid is enough, D&D would only reorder records in this case.